# ¿Cómo se expresa nombres de familias?

Tags: traducción, plurales, nombres-propios

Suponga que tengo planes a visitar una familia. Mi papá me pregunta a quién voy a visitar. ¿Cómo le contesto?

En inglés contestaríamos así:

> I'm going to visit **the Smiths**.

Más ejemplos:

> **The Browns** are very nice neighbors.
>
> How do you know **the Coopers**?

¿Hay una manera de expresar lo mismo en español? Lo que pensé era algo como:

> **Los Garcias** *(¿Y si esto es correcto, cómo lo haría para un nombre como "Rodriguez"? ¿Los Rodriguezes?*
>
> **La familia Garcia**

Comment: En España (y en la cultura latina en general), no existe la costumbre de compartir apellido. Por lo que no es normal decir "La familia García". Solo tendría sentido si quedaras con la rama de unos de los conyuges.

Comment: En México, al menos, se conoce a una familia por el apellido paterno aún si la madre no lo comparte. Por ejemplo Si Pedro Pérez y María López son padres de Juan y Laura Pérez, colectivamente sí son llamados los Pérez, o los Pérez-López.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> voy a visitar a los García

o

> voy a visitar a los Rodríguez

Es incorrecto decir "garcias" o rodrígueces".

Comment: Y como ejemplo bastante común y conocido, tenemos la serie de **Los Simpson**

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, en Argentina, no se utiliza una expresión como esta:

> *"voy a visitar a Los Gonzalez"...*

Hay gente que la usa, en determinados casos, pero no es muy usual, en general, se dice a la casa de quien vas a ir, señalando a un miembro de la familia:

> *"Voy a visitar a Matias"...*

-

> *"Voy a casa de Gonzalez"...*

-

> *"Voy a casa de Marta, una compañera del laburo"...* (trabajo)

-

> *"Voy a la casa, de esta gente"...* (En caso de que el que oye, sabe de quiénes hablas).